# How do I apply multiprocessing to a function in the inner loop of a nested loop while still running code in the outer loop?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement the algorithm from [this paper](https://aclanthology.org/2023.findings-acl.426.pdf), seen below.

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

k = 16
training_set = np.array([('TCCCTACACT', 9),
          ('AGTTGGTATT', 12),
          ('AGTGGATCAC', 8),
          ('CGCAAGTGTG', 3),
          ('CTGTTCCCCC', 7),
          ('CGACTGGTAA', 10),
          ('CGCCGAGAAG', 4),
          ('TAGCTACGAC', 5),
          ('CCTTGCGCGT', 11),
          ('CCAAAAGAAA', 12),
          ('CCTCAGGAGG', 6),
          ('AGGCCACTTA', 5),
          ('GCGGGAACGG', 5),
          ('CTATTACCAA', 2),
          ('ACACTTTTTT', 8),
          ('GATGCAGCGT', 1)])
test_set= np.array([('GATGCAGCGT', 3),
           ('GATGCAGCGT', 0),
           ('GATGCAGCGT', 3),
           ('GATGCAGCGT', 4)])
for ( x1, _ ) in test_set:
    Cx1 = len( gzip . compress ( x1.encode() ) )
    distance_from_x1 = []
    for ( x2, _ ) in training_set:
        Cx2 = len( gzip.compress(x2.encode()))
        x1x2 = " ".join([ x1 , x2 ])
        Cx1x2 = len( gzip.compress ( x1x2.encode() ))
        ncd = ( Cx1x2 - min( Cx1 , Cx2 ) ) / max(Cx1 , Cx2 )
        distance_from_x1.append( ncd )
    sorted_idx = np.argsort ( np.array(distance_from_x1 ) )

    top_k_class = list(training_set [ sorted_idx[: k] , 1])
    predict_class = max(set( top_k_class ) ,key = top_k_class.count )
    print(predict_class)
```

However, as the computation time explodes with the length of the dataset, I'm trying to implement multiprocessing. My intuition says that multiprocessing the inner loop would be the biggest time saver. I've seen answers to other questions on how to do multiprocessing on nested loops, but none with the caveat that other code still has to be run outside the inner loop but within the outer loop.

I've tried this code:

```
import gzip
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
def calculate_ncd(x1, x2):
    Cx1 = len(gzip.compress(x1.encode()))
    Cx2 = len(gzip.compress(x2.encode()))
    x1x2 = " ".join([x1, x2])
    Cx1x2 = len(gzip.compress(x1x2.encode()))
    ncd = (Cx1x2 - min(Cx1, Cx2)) / max(Cx1, Cx2)
    return ncd

def process_train_sample(x1, x2):
    return calculate_ncd(x1, x2)

def process_test_sample(test_sample):
    x1, _ = test_sample
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    distance_from_x1 = pool.starmap(process_train_sample, [([x1] * len(training_set), training_set)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    sorted_idx = np.argsort(np.array(distance_from_x1))
    top_k_class = list(training_set[sorted_idx[:k], 1])
    predict_class = max(set(top_k_class), key=top_k_class.count)
    return predict_class

k = 16
training_set = np.array([('TCCCTACACT', 9),
          ('AGTTGGTATT', 12),
          ('AGTGGATCAC', 8),
          ('CGCAAGTGTG', 3),
          ('CTGTTCCCCC', 7),
          ('CGACTGGTAA', 10),
          ('CGCCGAGAAG', 4),
          ('TAGCTACGAC', 5),
          ('CCTTGCGCGT', 11),
          ('CCAAAAGAAA', 12),
          ('CCTCAGGAGG', 6),
          ('AGGCCACTTA', 5),
          ('GCGGGAACGG', 5),
          ('CTATTACCAA', 2),
          ('ACACTTTTTT', 8),
          ('GATGCAGCGT', 1)])
test_set= np.array([('GATGCAGCGT', 3),
           ('GATGCAGCGT', 0),
           ('GATGCAGCGT', 3),
           ('GATGCAGCGT', 4)])

results = [process_test_sample(sample) for sample in test_set]# Process test samples in parallel


print(results)  # Print the predicted classes
```

But from what I've seen managing the pool overhead in each iteration of the outer loop is inefficient and the computation time increases.

I would like to know how to use a pool for each turn of the inner loop without having to manage the overhead of the pool on each turn of the outer loop.

EDIT: I've added dummy data since the actual data is hundreds of thousands of nucleotides long.

Comment: Please show the actual code you've tried. What you've shown will raise a NameError exception

Comment: Sorry, I copied it from a cell of a jupyter note book, forgetting that the cell relied on code in previous cells. The previous code took the strings from a dataframe made from a database so I've added a shortened version of each string with its label so hopefully it should run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to leverage the shared memory (to not copy the values back and forth):

```py
import gzip
import numpy as np

from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import ShareableList


def do_work(args):
    k = 16

    sl1, sl2, sl3, (x1, _) = args
    training_set = ShareableList(name=sl1.shm.name)
    training_set_lengths = ShareableList(name=sl2.shm.name)
    training_set_values = ShareableList(name=sl3.shm.name)

    Cx1 = len(gzip.compress(x1.encode()))

    distance_from_x1 = []
    for x2, Cx2 in zip(training_set, training_set_lengths):
        x1x2 = " ".join([x1, x2])
        Cx1x2 = len(gzip.compress(x1x2.encode()))
        ncd = (Cx1x2 - min(Cx1, Cx2)) / max(Cx1, Cx2)
        distance_from_x1.append(ncd)

    sorted_idx = np.argsort(np.array(distance_from_x1))
    top_k_class = [training_set_values[idx] for idx in sorted_idx[:k]]
    predict_class = max(set(top_k_class), key=top_k_class.count)
    return predict_class


if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = 16
    training_set = [
            ("TCCCTACACT", 9),
            ("AGTTGGTATT", 12),
            ("AGTGGATCAC", 8),
            ("CGCAAGTGTG", 3),
            ("CTGTTCCCCC", 7),
            ("CGACTGGTAA", 10),
            ("CGCCGAGAAG", 4),
            ("TAGCTACGAC", 5),
            ("CCTTGCGCGT", 11),
            ("CCAAAAGAAA", 12),
            ("CCTCAGGAGG", 6),
            ("AGGCCACTTA", 5),
            ("GCGGGAACGG", 5),
            ("CTATTACCAA", 2),
            ("ACACTTTTTT", 8),
            ("GATGCAGCGT", 1),
        ] # * 50_000

    test_set = np.array(
        [("GATGCAGCGT", 3), ("GATGCAGCGT", 0), ("GATGCAGCGT", 3), ("GATGCAGCGT", 4)] # * 10
    )

    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm, Pool() as pool:
        training_set_sl = smm.ShareableList([str(x2) for x2, _ in training_set])
        training_set_values = smm.ShareableList([int(val) for _, val in training_set])
        training_set_comp_lengths = smm.ShareableList([len(gzip.compress(x2.encode())) for x2, _ in training_set])

        for i, result in enumerate(pool.imap(do_work, ((training_set_sl, training_set_comp_lengths, training_set_values, t) for t in test_set), chunksize=1)):
            print(i, result)
```

With `training_set` of length `800_000` and `test_set` of length `40` I've managed to run it under one minute (`58,7s` on my 8C/16T 5700X, Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.10.9).

Comment: This is the comment that has worked best for me; with 640 total samples and an 80-20 split it took 1 day and 45 minutes to run. The bottleneck is the gzip compression time, but there's no way around that I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the overhead of the multithreading is too much for it to be worth it, don't use it. You mean you want to keep the pool 'open' and reuse it for all outer loop iterations? That sounds like you parallelize both loops. Why not parallelize both loops? That surely is the quickest way to calculate a grid of X1, X2 combinations. However, you could also create a pool and in each task for that pool perform the loop.

Comment: How would I parallelize both loops?

Comment: You could use 

pool.starmap((function, [(x1,x2) for ( x1, _ ) in test_set for ( x2, _ ) in training_set]), where function is a function doing the calculations for a pair of x1 and x2.

Comment: How do I run the code outside of the pairwise function? I.e. how do I get a distance_from_x1 list for each x1 and then return the predicted class for each x1?